# Reporte FPDF con gráfico con datos obtenidos de MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js, fpdf

Estoy generando mi reporte con gráfica por medio de FPDF, PHP y MySQL.

En mi base de datos ya tengo un cierto número de alumnos, con esos datos dentro de un While recorro mi base de datos y genero un reporte por cada alumno, dicho reporte debe de llevar un gráfico con esos mismo resultados (por cada alumno). Ya hice que ese gráfico por medio de base64 y enviándolo por POST se coloque en mi reporte, el problema lo tengo a la hora al querer hacer que ese gráfico se genere conforme avance el recorrido de mi base de datos.

**EN TERMINOS SIMPLES REQUIERO QUE POR CADA FILA EN MI BASE DE DATOS SE GENERE UNA GRÁFICA.**

El código que me genera el gráfico es el siguiente:

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" heigth="400"></canvas>
<form action="MockMainSuite.php?foo=" method="post" name="submit_encodeCanvas">
    <input type="text" name="name_encodeCanvas" id="id_encodeCanvas">
</form>           
<br>
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ['Reading', 'Writing', 'Listening'],
        datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: ["105", "80", "95"],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(48, 217, 220, 0.7)',
            'rgba(48, 217, 220, 0.7)',
            'rgba(48, 217, 220, 0.7)',
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(41, 181, 183, 1)',
            'rgba(41, 181, 183, 1)',
            'rgba(41, 181, 183, 1)',
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
        y: {
            beginAtZero: true
        }
        }
    }
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
    var fullQuality = canvas.toDataURL('img/jpeg',1.0);
    document.getElementById("id_encodeCanvas").value = fullQuality;
    document.submit_encodeCanvas.submit();
</script>
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Por cada fila en mi base de datos tengo que generar un grafico.